# Empty Object Receiving In Node JS Backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, multipartform-data, mern

I want to use form data to upload image using filesystem but unfortunately I am unable to receive fields on backend even after adding urlencoded middleware. My Code For app.js

```
import db from "./db";
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import routes from "./routes";
import cors from "cors";

export default function () {
  const app = express();
  dotenv.config({ path: ".env.local" });
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(cors());

  db(app);
  routes(app);
}
```

I tried multiple approaches but nothing worked. Here is the screenshot of my postman request

[image]

Api basically returns `res.json(body)`

I tried adding headers like multipart/form-data but it didn't work.

Comment: You need specific middleware like Multer to handle `multipart/form-data`